# Reading null values from csv in XSLT code without shifting the cells values

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I have these two lines from csv file

```
<ROOT>
1,M,40,0,5,0,Personeelsvoorschot,0
2,M,40,0,6,0,Personeelsvoorschot,0
</ROOT>
```

in XSLT code I get every cell in a tag as below (line number , dummy 1 , etc..), but the issue happened when I try to put any cell with null value and make a test, the tag not get null , it gets the next cell value which is wrong , I will appreciate your help

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"  indent="no" byte-order-mark="no"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<!--<xsl:preserve-space elements="*"/>-->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy >
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:key name="k1" match="row" use="cell[0]"/>
<xsl:key name="k2" match="row" use="concat(cell[1], '|', cell[3])"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="ProcessSalaryJournals">
            <xsl:variable name="rows">
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="ProcessADPMultilinkSalaryJournalUpload/DataArea/ADPMultilinkSalaryJournalUpload/ADPMultilinkSalaryJournalUploaddocument/ROOT"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="data">
                <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($rows)/row[position() > 0]">
                    <row>
                        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="','"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'cell'"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </row>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>
            <!-- output -->
            <SalaryJournals>
            <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($data)/row[count(. | key('k1', cell[1])[1]) = 1]">
                    <SalaryJournal>
                        <LineNumber>
                            <xsl:value-of select="cell[1]"/>
                        </LineNumber>
                        <Dummy1>
                            <xsl:value-of select="cell[2] " />
                        </Dummy1>
                        <Dummy2>
                            <xsl:value-of select="cell[3] " />
                        </Dummy2>
                        <Dummy3>
                            <xsl:value-of select="cell[4] " />
                        </Dummy3>
                        <Dummy4>
                            <xsl:value-of select="cell[5] " />
                        </Dummy4>
                        <Dummy5>
                            <xsl:value-of select="cell[6] " />
                        </Dummy5>
                        <VoucherText>
                            <xsl:value-of select="cell[7] " />
                        </VoucherText>
                        <AccountingDate>
                            <xsl:value-of select="cell[8] " />
                        </AccountingDate>
                    </SalaryJournal>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </SalaryJournals>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'&#10;'"/>
    <xsl:param name="name" select="'row'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
    <xsl:if test="$token">
        <xsl:element name="{$name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$token"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="name" select="$name"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: How does the input data look exactly for a "null" value? Why does the XSLT have `version="2.0"` but uses very XSLT 1.0 idioms like Muenchian grouping and a named template to tokenize although XSLT 2.0 has `for-each-group` and the `tokenize` function?

Comment: the data will be like 
1,M,,0,5,,Personeelsvoorschot,0
instead of 
1,M,40,0,5,0,Personeelsvoorschot,0

Comment: Do you use an XSLT 2.0 processor?

Comment: I think the `xsl:if test="$token"` needs to be removed

Comment: yes it works when I remove xsl:if test="$token" 

Thanks :)

Comment: Good, I posted that as an answer you can accept to mark your question as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `xsl:if test="$token"` needs to be removed if the template for tokenization needs to find empty string tokens like the empty string between two commas in `1,M,,0,5,,Personeelsvoorschot,0`.